# Scala Future[myType] to MyType

Tags: scala, future

I have Future[MyType] and I need to pass the value of MyType to a method which returns Seq[Future[MyType]], so basic signature of problem is:

```
val a: Seq[Future[MyType]] = ...

getValue(t: MyType): Seq[Future[MyType]] = {...}
```

I want to pass value of a to getValue. I tried something like:

```
val b:Seq[Future[MyType]] = a.map{v => getValue(v)}
```

I want b to be of `Seq[Future[MyType]]` type

but, it obviously didn't worked as v is of type Future[MyType] and getValue needs only MyType as parameter. What could be a possible solution??

Comment: You have `Seq[Future[MyType]]` which means you have multiple `Future[MyType]`. Does it matter which one you pull out to pass to `getValue()`? The first in the sequence? The first to complete with `Success`?

Comment: jwvh, I need to pass all the Success ones

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
val b = a.map(_.map(getValue(_)))
```

This will give you a `Seq[Future[Seq[Future[MyType]]]]`. That's pretty ugly. There are three tools that can make that better.

1. `Future.sequence` takes a `Seq[Future[A]]` and gives you a `Future[Seq[A]]`. The output future will wait for all input futures to complete before giving a result. This might not always be what you want.
2. `fut.flatMap` takes a function computing a `Future` as a result but does not return a nested Future, as would happen with `.map`.
3. You can call `.flatten` on a `Seq[Seq[A]]` to get a `Seq[A]`

Putting this all together, you could do something like:

```
val b: Seq[Future[Seq[MyType]] = a.map(_.flatMap(x => Future.sequence(getValue(x))))
val c: Future[Seq[MyType]] = Future.sequence(b).map(_.flatten)
```

More generally, when dealing with "container" types, you'll use some combination of `map` and `flatMap` to get at the inner types and pass them around. And common containers often have ways to flatten or swap orders, e.g. `A[A[X]] => A[X]` or `A[B[X]] => B[A[X]]`.

Comment: Thank a lot Joe K, I understand what you did but is there any way to convert `c: Future[Seq[MyType]]` to `c: Seq[Future[MyType]]`??

Comment: Probably not. Think of it this way: a `Future[Seq[MyType]]` could eventually complete with an empty Seq or one with 100 elements. So if you converted it to a `Seq[Future[MyType]]`, what should be the result of `.size` on that object? Sure, you could just wait for the future to complete before answering, but then why not just do that anyway and just get a plain `Seq[MyType]`?